# ¿Qué significado tiene la palabra "chapuza"?

Tags: etimología, significado

He escuchado la palabra *chapuza* y me ha llamado la atención. Quisiera saber cuál es su significado y su origen. ¿De dónde proviene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el diccionario de la lengua española, tiene dos acepciones, más una que es propia sólo en México:

> [**chapuza**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8baa46k)
>   `De chapuz`<sup>`2`</sup>`.`
>
> 1. f. Obra o trabajo, generalmente de mantenimiento, de poca importancia.
> 2. f. Trabajo hecho mal y sin esmero.
> 3. f. Méx. estafa (‖ acción de estafar).

Personalmente sólo había oído la segunda (trabajo mal hecho).

Ahí mismo dice que viene de la segunda entrada para *[chapuz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8baFHy9)*, que a su vez dice venir del francés antiguo *chapuis*, cuyo significado sería *tajo para trabajar sobre él*.

Según Wictionary en francés —si hemos de darle crédito—, *chapuis* en [fr. antiguo significa](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chapuis) *carpintero* y *madera de carpintero* y aparentemente viene en último término del latín *scapus/-i* que significa *tronco*:

> lat. *scapus* > *capo* > fr. ant. *chapon* > *chapouier* > *chapuis* > esp. *chapuz* > **chapuza**